# Left join on month and year (not date) in SQL

Tags: sql, date, join

I am trying to join 2 datasets on their ID and a date field in SQL, using the below code

```
CREATE TABLE new_data
SELECT A.*, B.`number`, B.`level`
FROM data1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN data2 AS B 
ON A.ID=B.ID
AND A.date=B.join_date
```

However, the dates that they should be joining on aren't exactly the same, so I want the join to be on just the month and year, NOT the day. The dates are in the format 0000-00-00. but are varchar.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

From the syntax I would guess you are using MariaDB or MySQL. If this is the case, you can use `SUBSTRING()` in the join predicate.

For example, if you need to join using the first 7 characters of the columns, you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE new_data
SELECT A.*, B.`number`, B.`level`
FROM data1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN data2 AS B 
  ON A.ID=B.ID
 AND substring(A.date, 1, 7) = substring(B.join_date, 1, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like "The Impaler" answered before you can use substring, but if in the case you want to use it with any nvarchar structure only changing a number and not counting characters on a string, then you can use convert() and specify an style/format for date convertion.

I'll put here the link that describes all the styles/formats on convert() sql function:
[Convert() SQL Function Definition](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp)

So, you said your nvarchar structure is the following: '0000-00-00', then you have to use the 102 style/format as the third parameter and set the data type as date on your convert() sql function.

An example of this:

```
select * from #T01 as T1
left join #T02 as T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,t1.DATE1,102)) = YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,t2.DATE2,102))
AND MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,t1.DATE1,102)) = MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,t2.DATE2,102))
```